# No puedo insertar en BD con CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, formularios, codeigniter-3, model-view-controller

Tengo una vista con un formulario Modal PopUp cuando se ejecuta el boton de aceptar no Inserta en la BD ni marca ningun error, espero me puedan ayudar.

VISTA:

```
    <!-- Modal (PopUp registro de nuevo cliente) -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Nuevo Cliente</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <?php echo form_open('cCliente/Insertar'); ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="TF_Nombre" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                          <input class="form-control" id="TF_Nombre" name="TF_Nombre">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="TF_RFC1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">RFC</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                          <input class="form-control" id="TF_RFC1" name="TF_RFC1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="Ok" name="Ok">Agregar</button>                                      
                    </div>
                    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                </form>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>

            </div>
```

CONTROLADOR

```
    <?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class cCliente extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mente');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data = array('titulo' => 'Factura');
        $this->load->view('Plantillas/head', $data);


        $this->load->view('Plantillas/nav');
        $this->load->view('Vistas/vFactura');
        $this->load->view('Plantillas/footer');
    }

    public function Insertar()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('TF_Nombre','Nombre','required|trim|xss_clean')
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('TF_RFC1','RFC','required|trim|xss_clean')

        if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
        {
            $this->index();
        }
        else
        {
            $TF_Nombre        = $this->input->post('TF_Nombre');
            $RFC                = $this->input->post('TF_RFC1');

            $insert = $this->MCliente->inserta_Cliente($TF_Nombre,$RFC);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

MODELO:

```
    <?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MCliente extends CI_Model 
{
    public function construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function inserta_Cliente($TF_Nombre,$RFC)
    {
        $data = array('NOMBRE' => $TF_Nombre,
                        'RFC'   => $RFC);
        $this->db->insert('clientes',$data);
    }
}

?>
```

De antemano muchas gracias.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si usas codeigniter 3, tu controlador `cCliente` debería llamarse **CCliente** ya que el formato para declarar controladores es declarar la clase siempre con una letra mayúscula inicial revisa la documentación oficial [Codeigniter 3](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html).

Al momento de insertar comprueba si se ejecuto correctamente el query, podrias hacer algo así en tu modelo **MCliente**:

```
public function inserta_Cliente($TF_Nombre,$RFC)
{
    $data = array('NOMBRE' => $TF_Nombre,
                    'RFC'   => $RFC);
    return $this->db->insert('clientes',$data);

}
```

Con eso estas retornando TRUE o FALSE de acuerdo a como se haya ejecutado el insert si no se ejecuto retorna FALSE.

En  tu controlador para comprobar si se inserto podrías imprimir el valor de $insert y ver si devuelve TRUE o FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que estás importando un modelo "mente"

```
$this->load->model('mente');
```

y cuando tratas de ejecutar ese modelo estás llamando al modelo "mCliente"

```
$insert = $this->MCliente->inserta_Cliente($TF_Nombre,$RFC);
```

Intenta cambiar "mente" por "MCliente"

Answer (score 0):

Creo que le falta el controlador de destino al formulario con action:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="controladorDestino.php" role="form">
</form>
```